# Finitely Co-generator

Tags: modules

Let M be an R-module. We say that M to be Co-generator. If for any family $(M_{i})_{i\in I}$, I is non-empty set, $M_{i}$ is submodule of M such that ${O_{M}}=\cap_{i\in I} M_{i}$ then 
there is $B\subset I$ is finite that ${O_{M}}=\cap_{i \in B} M_{i}$.

But we have some modules such that any family $(M_{i})_{i\in I}$ if they satisfy ${O_{M}}=\cap_{i \in I} M_{i}$, then there must be $i\in I$ that $M_{i}={0}$:

Example: V is K-vector space with 1-dimensional.

Now, we only consider the modules such that there is a family $(M_{i})_{i\in I}$, I is non-empty set, $M_{i}$ is submodule and $M_{i} \neq {0}$ for all $i\in I$ such that ${O_{M}}=\cap_{i\in I} M_{i}$.

Then my question is :

Whether the following assertion is right?

for any family $(M_{i})_{i\in I}$, I is non-empty set, $M_{i}$ is submodule of M such that ${O_{M}}=\cap_{i\in I} M_{i}$ then 
there is $B\subset I$ is finite that ${O_{M}}=\cap_{i\in B} M_{i}$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ there is $n\in N$, $x_{1},...,x_{n}\in M$ and $x_{1},...,x_{n} \neq 0$ such that ${O_{M}}=(x_{1}) \cap ... \cap (x_{n})$.

the direction $\Longrightarrow$ is easy by hypothesis:

there is a family $(M_{i})_{i\in I}$, I is non-empty set, $M_{i}$ is submodule and $M_{i}\neq {0}$ for all $i\in I$ such that ${O_{M}}=\cap_{i\in I} M_{i}$

so we choose $x_{i}\in M_{i}$, $x_{i} \neq 0$ then ${O_{M}}=\cap_{i\in I} (x_{i})$, so there is $n\in N$, $x_{1},...,x_{n} \in M$ and $x_{1},...,x_{n} \neq 0$ such that  ${O_{M}}=(x_{1})\cap ... \cap (x_{n})$.

Can you help me investigating the inverse direction?.

Comment: What is $O_M{}$?

Comment: M is albelian, so M has neutral element $0_{M}$.

Comment: Oh, Now, we consider the module such that there is a family $(M_{i})_{i\in I}$, I is non-empty set, $M_{i}$ is submodule and $M_{i} \neq {0}$ for all $i\in I$ such that ${O_{M}}=\cap_{i\in I} M_{i}$. And I want to check the above proposotion

Comment: My mean with the module having a family $(M_{i})_{i\in I}$, I is non-empty set, $M_{i}$ is submodule and $M_{i} \neq {0}$ for all $i\in I$ such that ${O_{M}}=\cap_{i\in I} M_{i}$. I want to form a equivalent condition for Co-generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse direction is not true.  For instance, let $k$ be a field and consider the ring $R=k[x,y]/(xy)$ as a module over itself.  Then $(x)\cap (y)=0$, so the second condition holds.  But, for instance, we can define $M_i=(x^i)$, and then $\bigcap M_i=0$ even though no finite intersection of the $M_i$ is $0$.